# How to detect the Popup LostFocus when only clicked outside the Popup and not to make the popup hidden

Tags: c#, uwp, popup

I have a custom UWP Control where i use Popup in it and how can i detect the Popup Lost Focus?

I have several tabs in my control and when i click any of my tab, the popup should be visible and vise versa and i have states for my tab to indicate the popup state.

Now i need to close the Popup when clicked outside the popup. I have done my research and found a property *IsLightDismissEnabled* which does close the Popup automatically and invokes LostFocus. But when switching between the Tabs the popup should not be closed , but when i use this property the popup is automatically closing which is not i desired.

This is the code i have
In the code im updating the state based on whether Popup is already open and whether new tab is selected.
And in State property im updating the Popup visibility

```
if (this.PART_Popup != null)
      {
           this.PART_Popup.LostFocus += this.PART_Popup_LostFocus;
           this.PART_Popup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
       }


private void PART_Popup_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {

        if (this.ParentItemsControl != null)
            {
                if (this.ParentItemsControl.State == State.Adorner)
                {
                    if (this.ParentItemsControl.PART_Popup.IsOpen && this.ParentItemsControl.SelectedItem == this)
                    {
                        this.ParentItemsControl.State = State.Hide;
                    }
                }
          else
                {
                    this.ParentItemsControl.State = State.Normal;
                }
            }
        }
```

Is there any way to invoke only LostFocus and i can have my code whether to close the Popup or stay it open(When Switching Tabs) ??
I also found when enabling the mentioned property, some double tap events were not working and i dont know why . So any help is appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

When you use the property `IsLightDismissEnabled`, it will always close the `Popup` and I don't think you shouldn't use this property if you are willing to keep the functionality of your custom control. Rather you should handle the opening and closing manually.

I think instead of trying to handle the `LostFocus` event, You should try the `Opened` and `Closed` event instead and utilize the writable property [`IsOpen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup.isopen) to manually open and close the `Popup`.

Hope that helps